# Problema al obtener el nombre de ID

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo varios botones, les asigno esta función, lo que quiero obtener el nombre del `ID` dependiendo del `botón` que se haya pulsado, ya pude obtener el valor entero *(del identificador)* pero necesito el `String` del identificador

```
public  void BorrarProducto (View v)
{
   int resID = v.getId();
   String NombreID = getString(resID);
   CantidadProductos.setText("" + NombreID);
}
```

Comment: ¿Te funciona el `String.valueOf(NombreID)` o `Integer.toString(NombreID)`?

Comment: Cuando yo muestro esto  CantidadProductos.setText("" + NombreID);             me imprime un "False" cuando muestro esto :CantidadProductos.setText("" + resID); me muestra el numero entero del ID lo que necesito es obtener el Nombre, el String del ID a partir del numero entero del ID que obtengo cuando se pulsa el boton

Comment: Con Integer.toString me parace el numero entero del ID

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que si el ID es 4 entonces debería decir 'cuatro'?. ¿O a qué te refieres con el String del ID?

Comment: Yo tengo botones y les asigno un ID, boton1, boton2, boton3 etc. cuando se presiona llamo al metodo "BorrarProducto" en el metodo obtengo el valor del ID con v.getId(); ahora lo que quiero es apartir de ese Valor obtenido del ID ej. 2131427427 obtener el nombre del ID Ej. "boton1"

Comment: @JesusAlbertoRomero esto es de Android de casualidad?

Comment: Si, es Android Studio

Comment: @JesusAlbertoRomero heheh puedes usar entonces  getResourceEntryName() , agrego en mi respuesta...

Answer (score 1):

Desde el evento donde invoques llama al `ev.getSource()` que invoca desde que componente se esta ejecutando el evento, deberia quedar algo asi  ahi imprime el boton presionado. si solo si todos tus botones estan inscritos `btn.addActionListener(this);` al mismo evento:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
   Object fuente = ev.getSource;
   System.out.printLn(fuente.getClass().getName());
}
```

Comment: Era lo que no queria...por que asi asignaria un if para cada boton (Son muchos) lo que quiero hacer es obtener el nombre del id, mis nombres al final tienen un numero boton1, boton2, boton3, etc, ya teniendo ese nombre contar los caracteres del Id, utilizar el ultimo, si es del 1 al 9 o los ultimos 2 si es del 10 al 99 hacer un casting para pasarlos a enteros y utilizar ese entero

Comment: Ahi veras el nombre del botón, recuerda inscribirlos al mismo evento

Comment: @JesusAlbertoRomero ¿y si creas un método que reciba por parámetro un `Button`? Ya que no soy exporto en java, te comento un ejemplo: `public String obtenerNombreBoton(Button btn) { System.out.printLn(btn.getClass().getName());  }`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes realizar mediante el método **[getResourceEntryName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName(int))**, que usarías de esta forma:

```
int resID = v.getId();
//Obtiene el nombre de la vista mediante el id definido en R.java
String nombre = getResourceEntryName getResources().getResourceEntryName(resID);
```

---

Otra forma sería mediante la propiedad `setTag()` para asignarle el nombre:

```
v.setTag("BotonJesus");
```

y obtener el nombre mediante:

```
String nombre = v.getTag();
```

Answer (score 1):

Para transformar un valor entero (int) a un String puedes hacer uso de la función valueOf de la propia clase String tal y como indica el código de ejemplo

```
public  void BorrarProducto (View v) {
    int resID = v.getId();
    String nombreID = String.valueOf(resID);
    ...
}
```

Un saludo :)